How can I run SQL code from C# that uses two separate databases
I am trying to copy merge etc. data tables from different databases. I can do it in Microsoft SQL Server with a query, but I can't manage to work from C# because of connection strings I think. How should I do it?
Here's some sample SQL code:
SELECT 
    [person_gelis_id], 
    [person_id],
    [muayene_zamanı],
    [HASTA_KABUL],
    [AGIRLIK],
    [BOY],
    [DIASTOLIK_KAN_BASINCI],
    [SISTOLIK_KAN_BASINCI]
INTO 
    ahmet.dbo.new
FROM 
    ahmet.dbo.asl 
JOIN 
    TestDB.dbo.GP_MUAYENE ON ahmet.dbo.asl.person_gelis_id = TestDB.dbo.GP_MUAYENE.HASTA_KABUL

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2014 and C#. Thank you in advance.

What have you tried and what didn't work as expected?

How are you requesting the database ? using an ORM (Entity, Dapper...) or directly (SqlCommand) ? What have you tried to tell you can't query two database from your code ?

alternatively, if this is a one-time merge / data correction, you can also simply copy the content the "other" table into a new table in the same database, and then delete the new table once you're done your operations.

Use a linked server as described here?

When you get it to work in Management Studio it should work the same from within C# code when you use the same connection string.

i tried give one of database connection string as i can find how to use both for same command. and i connect both databases wiv visual studio sql connection tool.

As you may not be aware, SQL Server 2014 reached end of life earlier this year; you should really be looking to upgrade to a (fully) supported version of SQL Server.

To add to the "end of life" remark: this means your database server no longer receives any updates: not even critical security patches.

When you fully qualify a table name, such as ahmet.dbo.asl, you must give it an alias before referencing any columns.
If you don't, and attempt to reference a column via a name with four segments, instead of database.schema.table.column it's interpreted as server.database.schema.table, which is not what you want. This happens even in places where only a column name, rather than an object identifier, makes sense, and you can't change it; it's just how it is.
Therefore, when we see this in your code: ahmet.dbo.asl.person_gelis_id, it won't look for the person_gelis_id column in the asl table on the ahmet database. Instead it tries to resolve the name by looking for a server named ahmet, with a database named dbo and a table named person_gelis_id.
So instead you need to do this:
SELECT [person_gelis_id]
    ,[person_id]
    ,[muayene_zamanı]
    ,[HASTA_KABUL]
    ,[AGIRLIK]
    ,[BOY]
    ,[DIASTOLIK_KAN_BASINCI]
    ,[SISTOLIK_KAN_BASINCI]
INTO ahmet.dbo.new
FROM ahmet.dbo.asl a
JOIN TestDB.dbo.GP_MUAYENE m
    ON a.person_gelis_id = m.HASTA_KABUL

This is better practice anyway, even when you aren't writing cross-database queries.
